# Swift: How do I call this completion block only after code executes?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am having trouble understanding why this code is executing the completion block before users are appended to a category.

First I am trying to fetch the category. Each category has an array of user Id's, which are looped over to fetch a user from a separate location in my database.

Here is the Firebase data:

```
["Category 1": {
title = lifestyle;
users =     (
    ESKYpDMPiHW34,
    HJ8ItJDoExZMQ,
    1WDnoPy4PeQkm
);
}, "Category 2": {
title = fitness;
users =     (
    ESKYpDMPiHW3,
    HJ8ItJDoExZM,
    1WDnoPy4PeQk
);
}, "Category 3": {
title = health;
}]
```

**Here is my code:**

```
class func fetchFeaturedUsers(completion: @escaping ([UserCategory]) -> Swift.Void) {
    var categories = [UserCategory]()

    let dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("categories")
    dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in

        if let dict = snap.value as? [String: Any] {
            for (_, value) in dict {

                if let category = value as? [String:Any] {

                    let title = category["title"] as? String
                    let newCategory = UserCategory(title: title?.capitalized, users: [User]())
                    categories.append(newCategory)

                    if let users = category["users"] as? [String] {
                        for id in users {
                            User.fetchUser(userId: id, completion: { (newUser) in
                                newCategory.users?.append(newUser)
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(categories)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without adding it into the `DispatchQueue.main.async`?

Comment: Yes, nothing changes. Completion is still called first.

Comment: I think your issue is the `User.fetchUser` call is asynchronous, so the loop to fetch all the users completes before any of the calls return. So all your code executes, and then the completion block gets called.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `User.fetchUser` method is an asynchronous call that is being done in another thread. To solve that you can create a `DispatchGroup` that will wait until all calls be completed before calling `completion` like this:

```
class func fetchFeaturedUsers(completion: @escaping ([UserCategory]) -> Swift.Void) {
    var categories = [UserCategory]()
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    let dbRef = Database.database().reference().child("categories")
    dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in

        if let dict = snap.value as? [String: Any] {
            for (_, value) in dict {

                if let category = value as? [String:Any] {

                    let title = category["title"] as? String
                    let newCategory = UserCategory(title: title?.capitalized, users: [User]())
                    categories.append(newCategory)

                    if let users = category["users"] as? [String] {
                        for id in users {
                            dispatchGroup.enter()
                            User.fetchUser(userId: id, completion: { (newUser) in
                                newCategory.users?.append(newUser)
                                dispatchGroup.leave()
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)){
            completion(categories)                
        }
    })
}
```

You can read more about DispatchGroup in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup).

Comment: That's what I figured, and I tried the same code, but I get an (lldb) crash on dispatchGroup.leave().  Is this because there are a disproportionate number of leave() vs. enter()?

Comment: @CharlesBlack Yes, I just edited my code, `enter` must be inside the `for` loop, sorry for that.

Comment: Awesome! This is what I needed. Appreciate it.